# Tensorflow cannot split Unicode UTF-8 character

Tags: python, tensorflow, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I using `tf.strings.unicode_split` for split characters of text.
when I use English characters it's working correctly

```
example_texts = ['hello world']
chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(example_texts, input_encoding='UTF-8')
print(chars)

<tf.RaggedTensor [[b'h', b'e', b'l', b'l', b'o', b' ', b'w', b'o', b'r', b'l', b'd']]>
```

but if **change to UTF-8 Unicode** charactersit's not working like English character

```
example_texts = ['سلام دنیا']
chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(example_texts, input_encoding='UTF-8')
print(chars)

<tf.RaggedTensor [[b'\xd8\xb3', b'\xd9\x84', b'\xd8\xa7', b'\xd9\x85', b' ', b'\xd8\xaf', 
b'\xd9\x86', b'\xdb\x8c', b'\xd8\xa7']]>
```

thank you.

Comment: It looks correct to me. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I expecting split Persian characters like this: س ل ا م . not in like this: xd8\xb3 xd8\x84 ...

Comment: Apparently, the characters are encoded to UTF-8. In the English example the same happens (the characters are byte strings – cf. the byte prefix), and you don't seem to mind. Try this: `b'\xd8\xb3'.decode('utf8') == 'س'`, just like `b'h'.decode('utf8') == 'h'`.

Comment: I tried ".decode('utf-8') " and this worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

From Comments

> Apparently, the characters are encoded to UTF-8. In the English
> example the same happens (the characters are byte strings – cf. the
> byte prefix), and you don't seem to mind. To view Persian characters you try
> this: `b'\xd8\xb3'.decode('utf8')` == `'س'`, just like `b'h'.decode('utf8')` ==
> `'h'` (paraphrased from  lenz)